# Port forward traffic from restricted network with home unrestricted

Tags: port-forwarding, tcp, tunnel, relay

Here is the scenario: I have an enterprise e-mail whose SMTP server listens on port 2525. I can configure an e-mail client like thunderbird in my home without any problem. I also have another job, where most of outbounding ports are closed, including 2525. However, there are a few ports that ARE open for outbounding traffic.

Is there a way for me to use my home unrestricted network and router (and a linux system 24/7 there) to redirect traffic? I did once something alike with SSH tunneling to browse internet without proxy restrictions, but this is different.

What I have in mind: in restricted network: set SMTP to my home static IP on any open port I find. in home: redirect that port to (1) directly real SMTP on 2525 (2) local server and then redirect somehow to SMTP on 2525

so: what's the name of what I'm trying to do? how do you think I can achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **what's the name of what I'm trying to do?**

TCP relay

> **how do you think I can achieve that?**

[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES):

> ...
>
> ```
> socat TCP4-LISTEN:www TCP4:www.domain.org:www
> ```
>
> installs a simple TCP port forwarder. With TCP4-LISTEN it listens on local port "www" until a connection comes in, accepts it, then connects to the remote host (TCP4) and starts data transfer. It will not accept a second connection.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> socat -d -d -lmlocal2 \
> TCP4-LISTEN:80,bind=myaddr1,su=nobody,fork,range=10.0.0.0/8,reuseaddr \
> TCP4:www.domain.org:80,bind=myaddr2
> ```
>
> TCP port forwarder, each side bound to another local IP address (bind). This example handles an almost arbitrary number of parallel or consecutive connections by fork'ing a new process after each accept() . It provides a little security by su'ing to user nobody after forking; it only permits connections from the private 10 network (range); due to reuseaddr, it allows immediate restart after master process's termination, even if some child sockets are not completely shut down. With -lmlocal2, socat logs to stderr until successfully reaching the accept loop. Further logging is directed to syslog with facility local2.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> socat TCP4-LISTEN:5555,fork,tcpwrap=script \
> EXEC:/bin/myscript,chroot=/home/sandbox,su-d=sandbox,pty,stderr
> ```
>
> a simple server that accepts connections (TCP4-LISTEN) and fork's a new child process for each connection; every child acts as single relay. The client must match the rules for daemon process name "script" in /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny, otherwise it is refused access (see "man 5 hosts_access"). For EXEC'uting the program, the child process chroot's to /home/sandbox, su's to user sandbox, and then starts the program /home/sandbox/bin/myscript. Socat and myscript communicate via a pseudo tty (pty); myscript's stderr is redirected to stdout, so its error messages are transferred via socat to the connected client.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> socat EXEC:"mail.sh target@domain.com",fdin=3,fdout=4 \
> TCP4:mail.relay.org:25,crnl,bind=alias1.server.org,mss=512
> ```
>
> mail.sh is a shell script, distributed with socat, that implements a simple SMTP client. It is programmed to "speak" SMTP on its FDs 3 (in) and 4 (out). The fdin and fdout options tell socat to use these FDs for communication with the program. Because mail.sh inherits stdin and stdout while socat does not use them, the script can read a mail body from stdin. Socat makes alias1 your local source address (bind), cares for correct network line termination (crnl) and sends at most 512 data bytes per packet (mss).
>
> ...

Comment: Wonderful. Great quote from socat. Also thanks for pointing the name of the technique. Sometimes (specially for non-english speakers) it's just the lack of tools to google something.